# Exception SQL state [null]; error code [31]; The connection is closed: The connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, oracle12c, spring-jdbc

we are using our own data source  which is built on top of PoolDataSourceFactory

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory"
      factory-method="getPoolDataSource" lazy-init="true" >
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="connectionWaitTimeout" value="30" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="abandonedConnectionTimeout" value="300"/>
    <property name="inactiveConnectionTimeout" value="900"/>
    <property name="validateConnectionOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="exceptionManager" value="exceptionManager"/> 
</bean>
```

Tomcat Server Log:

2017-10-17 20:33:25,913 ERROR [http-nio-8101-exec-4] u: - JdbcStoredProcedureWrapper.selectUserDetails: Could not execute stored procedure: Exception [{}] org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call SP_NAME(?, ?, ?, )}]; SQL state [null]; error code [31]; The connection is closed: The connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The co nnection is closed: The connection is closed at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1137) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173) at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:142) at com.vodafone.gdsp.provisioning.dataaccess.jdbc.JdbcStoredProcedureCaller.execute(JdbcStoredProcedureCaller.java:561) at com.vodafone.gdsp.provisioning.dataaccess.jdbc.JdbcStore

I stuck with this issue if any help is highly appreciated

Please help me on the above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Struggling one week finally I fixed the Issue:

Solution: Most likely that a cursor is opened based on a global temporary table(GTT), which had been created with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS option. And the cause of the ORA-08103: object no longer exists error is commit statement that followed right after the delete statement. DBA team didn't agree to change the GTT as on commit preserve rows so finally I added code base in Java Service Layer[Implementing the Spring - Programmatic Transaction] but forgot to add transactionManager.rollback(status) int catch block this is causing the connection closed error.

FiX :

package com.test;

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
   public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
      this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
   }
   public void create(String name, Integer age, Integer marks, Integer year){
      TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

      try {
         String SQL1 = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
         jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL1, name, age);

         // Get the latest student id to be used in Marks table
         String SQL2 = "select max(id) from Student";
         int sid = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt( SQL2 );

         String SQL3 = "insert into Marks(sid, marks, year) " + "values (?, ?, ?)";
         jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL3, sid, marks, year);

         System.out.println("Created Name = " + name + ", Age = " + age);
         transactionManager.commit(status);
      } 
      catch (DataAccessException e) {
         System.out.println("Error in creating record, rolling back");
         **transactionManager.rollback(status);**
         throw e;
      }
      return;
   }
   public List<StudentMarks> listStudents() {
      String SQL = "select * from Student, Marks where Student.id=Marks.sid";
      List <StudentMarks> studentMarks = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
         new StudentMarksMapper());

      return studentMarks;
   }
}
```